# jquery .load() is slow. How to speed up?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been googling how to speed up .load() loading time but failed tp find any solutions.
Is just a simple loading of html table generated by external script.
The result took about 10sec while loading the table and without .load() takes just 2-3s.
It became worst when I use datatable plugin on the table. It can load as long as 25s
Is there anyway I can load the table faster?

index.php

```
<script>
$('#Table').load("ajaxtable.php?type=tableA");
.
.
.
</script>
<div id = 'Table'></div>
```

ajaxtable.php

```
if ($_GET["type"] == "tableA"){
//select * from DBtable;'
//result will generate 100 column by 500 rows result 
return;
}
```

Comment: if it is a huge dataset, can you limit the number of records you are retrieving, and introduce pagination?

Comment: I find that hard to believe that `$.load` takes 10 seconds but loading the page directly takes only 2. There's something you're not telling us. If you use the datatable plugin, that makes sense that it takes longer, it needs to modify the HTML, so if it's a large table, it's going to take awhile.

Comment: Hi Karthikr, I have introduce pagination using datatable. The no of records are fixed and required.

Comment: Javascript based sorting and pagination for large datasets can take quite a bit of resources. What's the timing like if you turn it off?

Comment: @user1761160 Don't just say "nothing to hide" show us proof that they behave differently, I still don't believe you.

Comment: Using datatable for pagination still loads the data upfront, you should do the pagination on the server so you only load the data needed at that moment

Comment: Dracs, disabling the datatable will take about 7s-10s.

Comment: send JSON to datatables instead of html